# Skinny Controller For ASP.NET MVC File Upload

Tags: asp.net-mvc, excel, file-upload, controller, n-tier-architecture

I am gradually converting a Classic ASP website to ASP.Net MVC. Within my Models folder I have further subdivided it into Business Objects (BO), Business Logic (BLL) and Data Access Layer (DAL) for basically a 3-tier architecture within Models. This seems to be working well so far with respect to database operations and it is keeping my controllers skinny. For example a typical controller would look like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    UserName UserDetails = UserManager.GetUserName();
    CarrierList CarrierList = CarrierManager.GetCarrierList();
    return View(new CarrierViewModel(CarrierList, UserDetails));                     
}
```

Basically I just use the controller to pass a function to the BLL layer which in turn interacts with the DAL & BO layers.

Where I am confused is the correct place for logic relating to non database operations such as file uploads. For example I am currently writing code to upload an Excel file and import its contents into a database table. If I were to follow the same pattern above, my controller should just contain a function to pass the file upload request to the BLL layer like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{   
    FileManager.ImportExcel(file);
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

The problem is that every tutorial or example I see for file uploads and Excel manipulation put their file and Excel code directly in the controller. eg [here](http://mvc4beginner.com/Sample-Code/ImportExportExcelData/MVC4-Import-ExcelData-to-Database.html). Even Scott Hanselman's post [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ABackToBasicsCaseStudyImplementingHTTPFileUploadWithASPNETMVCIncludingTestsAndMocks.aspx) seems to imply that it is OK to put file upload logic in the controller.

My question is, given my 3-tier ASP.NET MVC architecture and fat model/skinny controller design goal, am I on the right track by offloading the upload and Excel manipulation logic to the BLL within the model? It seems consistent with what I am trying to do, yet since  all the examples I see online just put the file manipulation logic in the controller, I feel like I am going against the grain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just get the stream and pass the stream to your BLL. That way your BLL is not depending on HttpPostedFileBase but just on a Stream.

Anyway, as it seems, your BLL code is inside your MVC application, which is not a very good idea. You should create a class library for the BLL, one for BO and one for DAL, and if possible wire them together loosely.

Comment: Why is it not a good idea to have BLL in MVC? I was basing my approach on [this](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/132/ASP.NET-MVC-is-not-all-about-Linq-to-SQL). One thing I can think of is that your suggestion re separate class libraries would lend itself to better code reuse for the console app that goes with this site.

Comment: Exactly. As an extra bonus it will also force you not to make 'inverse' calls (from your DAL to your BLL for example).

Comment: In a real-world scenario I even prefer to have ALL my code outside of the MVC project. The controllers and the model as well, they should go in a presentation-layer, not in the UI.

Comment: That makes sense. When I started porting my classic asp/vbscript app. I started converting the command line vbscripts one by one with all the logic for each vbscript contained in each C# app. Eventually I realized there was too much common logic so I took out the common logic and put it it own class library. I think you are suggesting the next step, which is to put all business logic in a separate class library that can be used by my web app and console app.

Comment: Also what do you mean "wire them together loosely"? Can't I just create a reference to each DLL from within my MVC project and then just refer to each function I need through its namespace?

Comment: Yes, that's one way to go, but if you really want loose coupling you should look into Dependency Injection. Warning: this is not easy to get in to but it offers a lot of advantages. There is an awesome book about this which I highly recommend: http://www.manning.com/seemann/ If you're interested in patterns, loose coupling, good design this book will rock your world

Comment: I have come back to this question a year later and can see exactly what you mean by many of your comments here. I am splitting my App into separate projects and can see the problem with using HttpPostedFileBase instead of stream. I also see that splitting my project into separate class libraries does help enforce separation of concerns. BTW, I am using Dependency Injection now. I've come a long way in one year.